# Inkscape unable to add the same stroke width to all paths

Tags: vector, inkscape, svg, stroke

Hi i just modified a text into paths and curved some paths, i attach an svg of my work.

Now i just would like to add stroke to the object so that i can make bold the text, but as you can see , trying adding some stroke, causes some paths to not get the same stroke.

Just try in inkscape to add stroke to this SVG and you will see the problem is clear :(

Any help appriciated! thanks

SVG: http://www.mediafire.com/download/3f8998s8s86yyi9/relt.svg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we can see as soon as we apply a fine stroke width and a fill our letters are made of both, objects, and lines:

[image]

This is how to make objects from strokes:

1. Select the object stroke (while in path tool [image])

   [image]
2. Now choose *Path > Stroke to Path* to convert the stroke to an object (here filled red with 2 px black stroke for illustration)

   [image]